# how to convert Pdf to image via imagemagick command?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, ubuntu-11.04

I am using following environment:

Ubunut : 11.0 (virtual machine)
Imagemagick : ImageMagick-6.9.3-7

I have execut following command:

```
wget http://www.imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick.tar.gz
tar xzvf ImageMagick.tar.gz
ls
cd ImageMagick<version number here>/
./configure
make clean
make
sudo make install
ldconfig /usr/local/lib
```

After executing below command:

```
make check
```

40 test case 39 pass only 1 is fail (FAIL: tests/wandtest.tap 1)

Now i want to convert pdf file to jpg via command:

```
convert test.pdf test.jpg
```

convert: no decode delegate for this image format `PNG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.
convert: no images defined`test.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3252

```
convert test.pdf test.png
```

convert: no decode delegate for this image format `PNG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.
convert: no images defined`test.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3252.

anyone can suggest me how can i do ?

Comment: You need to install the `ghostscript` package.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: can you provide a link from where i can see the installation process.

Comment: I don't have any specific suggestion, I just know that is the answer. Try something like this though I have no tested it https://gist.github.com/leomelzer/3949356

Comment: You'll also need to install `libpng` before configuring imagemagick.

Comment: This is slightly off-topic but you can also convert PDF directly from GhostScript which in my case runs much faster. To do so, execute:


`gs -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=jpeg -r150 -sOutputFile=output-%d.jpg input.pdf`

Comment: @rostok: after executing the given command . i am not able to see the output.jpg/ can you tell me where has file stored ?

Comment: @rostok: Thanks !!

Comment: See: http://superuser.com/q/819277/33767

Answer (score 2):

ImageMagick uses assorted external libraries to do its dirty work as far as input and output handling goes for various formats. In your case:

- For reading PDFs, you need to have Ghostscript installed. Also it needs to be in your path as `gs` in order to work, so don't use that for some other shell alias. For more details see: https://superuser.com/q/819277/33767
- For writing PNGs you'll need `libpng`.

Once those things are on your system (and in the case you compiled IM yourself, on your system at the time of compile) you should be golden.

Answer (score 2):

It may be that the issue is not with the writing but with the reading of the PDF itself.
Check the ImageMagick policy.xml.

```
sudo nano /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml
```

Find the PDF and change to this:

```
 <policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PDF" />
```

This solved for me.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. Solved it with:

```
apt-get -y install ghostscript
```